# How to add leading Zero's to make location number in Power BI so it returns 3 digit #

Tags: powerbi

*Loc1= FORMAT('Table'[LOC],"000")* Any suggestion would be helpful? The original Column LOC is a text field with returns 3 characters with leading Zero's. I need it in numeric form to be able to join and use it in calculated columns.

Answer (score 0):

Found a work around to fix my problem, I came up with a solution to keep Loc column as text and add concatenate column with Business Unit ID and Loc & convert concatenated col to numeric field so I can use for filtering and joining.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).